# Inno-Setup destination folder

Tags: inno-setup

Does anyone know how to use Inno-Setup to put a file into specified folder?

I would like to put a .xlam file into: %appdata%\Microsoft\Addins

I can't make it put anything into this folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this with ISPP:

```
[ISPP]
#define DataDir "{userappdata}\Microsoft\addins"

[Files]
Source: "C:\source\myapp\output\test.xlam"; DestDir: "{#DataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly; Attribs: readonly
```

But note that it is not always a good idea to use the `{userappdata}` folder. I have had instances where the installer is **elevated** and the data files end up in the **administrators** user area. Thus, I install these kind of files to the `{commonappdata}` folder and then when my application starts, it looks to see if it needs to copy any files from `{commonappdata}` to `{userappdata}`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the `{userappdata}` and `{commonappdata}` constants to get the `%appdata%` portion of the path.
You can't use the wizard, you'll need to add the entry manually.  It'll look something like:

```
Source: "C:\source\myapp\output\test.xlam"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\addins"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Comment: Can I use that when using the wizard?